# Brakes and low-pitched squeak

Tags: honda, brakes

I've had my 02 Honda CR-V for 3 months or so now and have noticed a growing squeak upon application of my brakes. This squeak is different from the normal high-pitched squeal that comes from the metal wear indicator. This sounds much more like when you take a large, old spring and push down on it. It's lower in pitch than the squeak of a spring suspensions.

When I press on the brakes from a high speed I can hear it squeaking quickly as the tires rotate. As I slow down, the squeak increases in duration of the sound and in length of time between squeaks.

I've looked at both [**this question**](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2058/clunking-sound-at-back-of-car-when-applying-brakes) & [**this one**](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/clunk-noise-from-my-brakes-on-first-application), too. But, it's not a "clunking" sound being made. I wanted to have a sound clip for you, but I've been unsuccessful at getting a recording of the noise :P

Any ideas, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Do your rotors have spots on them? Sometimes when the rotors overheat, they develop spots that cause different effects. Sometimes the vehicle will shutter and vibrate, other times it can make noise.